# Retrieving double redirects through MediaWiki API

Tags: javascript, mediawiki-api

I want to write a script to resolve double redirects automatically after a page move. Here is what I have started with:

```
(function () {
    var api = new mw.Api();
    api.get( {
        action: 'query',
        list: 'backlinks',
        blpageid: mw.config.get('wgArticleId'),
        blfilterredir: 'redirects',
        blredirect: true,
        bllimit: 500
    } ).done( function (data) {
        var fixed = 0;
        redirects = data.query.backlinks;
        for (var i=0; i<redirects.length; i++) {
            var doubles = redirects[i].redirlinks;
            if (doubles === undefined) {
                continue;
            }
            for (var j=0; j<doubles.length; j++) {
                console.log(doubles[j]);
                fixed ++;
            }
        }
        mw.notify(fixed);
    } );    
})();
```

The problem is that if I run this function on a page like [Wikipedia:Blocking policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blocking_policy) the script returns some pages that are not actually double-redirects, but merely redirects containing links to it.

I can check each of them to see where they are actually pointing to, but isn't there any better way? i.e. a simple method to retrieve double redirects only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with using python and the pywikibot framework there is https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/redirect.py which should do what you want.

Otherwise you might want to work with the output of [Special:DoubleRedirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:DoubleRedirects).

Comment: Actually I just missed the "after a move" bit of your question so this answer is probably not what you are looking for.